# Can a MongoDB value be a Hashmap and can that hash map be modeled in a Mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, hashmap, mongoose-schema

I've written the following MongooseJS schema.The field "likers" is an embedded record which currently is a POJO with two keys. Can the embedded schema be a hash map with each "liker" field serving as the key?

Here's what the hash map should look like :

```
const userlikers = {
  {'100900800' : 'user'}
  {'100989455' : 'user'}
  {'109099985' : 'user'}
}
```

Here's the current schema

```
const userlikers = Schema({
    users : {
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed
    }
})

const PicSchema = Schema ({
    url : {
        type : String, 
        required : true
    }, 
    desc : {
        type : String, 
        required : true
    },
    likers : [userlikers], 
    created : {
        by : {
            type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref : 'User', 
            required : true
        }, 
        at : {
            type : Date, 
            default : Date.now
        }
    }
})

const Pic = mongoose.model('Pic', PicSchema);

module.exports = Pic;
```

Comment: You can certainly have hash maps in mongo. Not familiar with mongoose enough to give you an answer on that part.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is so late,
From mongoose version 5.10.9 you can use the map instead of type: Schema.Types.Mixed

```
const PicSchema = Schema ({
    ..............
    ........
    likers : { 
            type: Map,
            of: String
           }, 
   ........
   ........
})
```

Comment: Not too late for me! Thanks